# What is the name of this (possibly classical) combinatorial optimization problem?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

I have a finite number of sets $S_i$, each of the sets costing $p_i$ and containing some elements. Given the budget $b$ I want to select number of those sets to maximize $|S_{k_1} \cup S_{k_2} \dots|$ with restriction $\sum_j p_{k_j} \leq b$.

I think it should be something classical, like knapsack problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the [Budgeted Maximum Coverage Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem#Budgeted_maximum_coverage), which shares some features with SUKP but has a different kind of objective and constraint function. Both problems are NP-hard, with *Budgeted Maximum Coverage* being a direct reduction from [*Set Cover*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

The data includes a finite family of finite sets $\{S_1,S_2,\ldots,S_n\}$, each with an associated nonnegative cost $p_i$ (or $c_i$ in the Wikipedia article).

The objective is to choose some of these sets, subject to the "budget constraint" that the sum of $p_i$ corresponding to that choice does not exceed $b$ (or $B$ in the Wikipedia article), in order to maximize the number of points "covered" by the selected sets, i.e. the size of their union.

Formally we can introduce $\{0,1\}$ variables $x_i$ that indicate the choice of sets $S_i$, which allows us to express the budget constraint as:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \cdot x_i \le b $$

In order to count the number of points covered by such a choice, we first index the points contained in $E = \bigcup_{i=1}^n S_i$ so that $e_j \in E$ is a typical point, $j = 1,\ldots,m$.  Then we introduce additional $\{0,1\}$ variables $y_j$ to indicate whether $e_j$ is covered.

This allows us to write the objective function:

$$ \text{ maximize } \sum_{j=1}^m y_j $$

subject to:

$$ \begin{align*} \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \cdot x_i \le b; & \text{ (cost cannot exceed budget) } \\
\sum_{i : e_j\in S_i} x_i \ge y_j & \text{ for each } j=1,\ldots,m; \\
y_j \in \{0,1\} & \text{ for each } j=1,\ldots,m; \\
x_i \in \{0,1\} & \text{ for each } i=1,\ldots,n. \end{align*}$$

This restricts, in a roundabout way, $y_j=1$ for only those points $e_j$ contained in at least one set $S_i$ for which $x_i=1$.  The objective function is easily modified to accomodate a weighted sum of the points being covered rather than a simple count of them.

See Khuller, Moss, and Naor (1999), [The Budgeted Maximum Coverage Problem](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~amzallag/awc/KMN99.pdf), for a review of the literature and a proposed approximation scheme via improvement upon a greedy heuristic.

This Budgeted Maximum Coverage Problem differs from the Set-Union Knapsack Problem, where the constraint is based on the total weights of chosen points $e_j$ and the objective function is evaluated by summing "profits" over all the sets $S_i$ which are fully populated by that choice of points.

Nonetheless Ashwin Arulselvan (2014) has [drawn a specialized connection between them](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2609085):

> Recently, Khuller, Moss and Naor presented a greedy algorithm for the budgeted maximum coverage problem. In this note, we observe that this algorithm also approximates a special case of a set-union knapsack problem within a constant factor. In the special case, an element is a member of less than a constant number of subsets. This guarantee naturally extends to densest k-subgraph problem on graphs of bounded degree.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems), this is called the Set-Union Knapsack Problem.

Comment: I'd be interested to see the correspondence between the OP's problem and the Set-Union Knapsack Problem in more detail.  The constraints and objective functions are at least superficially different.

Comment: @hardmath I am tempted to agree that the Wikipedia article isn't crystal clear, even though it quotes its reference book the informal description from the book verbatim. There is a formal definition in the book, but we shall never know what it is, because I can only find a Google book which omits all even-numbered pages. Nevertheless, from the description: *The total weight of a set of item is the total weight of the union of the corresponding element sets* and *the items have profits $p_j, j=1\ldots n$*, so I think they're talking about the same objective function as the OP.

Comment: @hardmath Perfect! I would appreciate that!

Comment: Let me see if I can get the complete reference from my local university library.